# How split and capture elements using id value in a 2D array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

So, the question here is I want to manipulate a 2D Array in javascript.

for example:

```
arr = [
[1, 1, 0, 5],
[1, 2, 2, 6],
[1, 3, 4, 7],
[1, 4, 6, 8],
[2, 1, 1, 1],
[2, 2, 3, 2],
[2, 3, 5, 3],
[2, 4, 7, 4]

];
```

In this array, there are 8 different elements. Now I want to achieve, where using the first and second element in the array. I want to differentiate between id 1 and 2[1] or b/w 1-4[2] and with this to add the 3rd element in total to get two different values.

Comment: the question is not clear

Comment: You can access element by arr[i][j] where i is the number of row and j is number of element in that row.

Comment: Give the sample output, that will help

Comment: @bkr I want to differentiate b/w 1 and 2 in the first column of the array or 1 - 4 from the second column of the array.

Comment: please add the wanted result of all.

Comment: @Harsh Patel, I tried that but, I was only getting an output for 1 element.

Comment: @Nina Wanted result will be 

output:
run id  1 = 12
run id  2 = 16

this is calculating from 3rd row.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a hash table for the first element and summ all other values.

```js
var array = [[1, 1, 0, 5], [1, 2, 2, 6], [1, 3, 4, 7], [1, 4, 6, 8], [2, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 3, 2], [2, 3, 5, 3], [2, 4, 7, 4]],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        if (!hash[a[0]]) {
            hash[a[0]] = [a[0], 0];
            r.push(hash[a[0]]);
        }
        hash[a[0]][1] += a[2];
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

If you like you could use just the hash table only. This includes a check for empty arrays.

```js
var array = [[], [1, 1, 0, 5], [1, 2, 2, 6], [1, 3, 4, 7], [1, 4, 6, 8], [2, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 3, 2], [2, 3, 5, 3], [2, 4, 7, 4]],
    result = Object.create(null);

array.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.length) {
        result[a[0]] = (result[a[0]] || 0) + a[2];
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: it is doing the job but, the value is shown as undefined.

this is the output I'm getting

Comment: can do this for an array length of 800?

Comment: NaN or undefined.

Comment: are all inner arrays filled with numerical values? or are some empty?

Comment: then add a check to prevent  empty arrays, like in the second example.

Comment: I'm using the second method for checking an array and this was the output:

' 1 ': '0 1  11  11  40  37  40  40  49 ',
  ' 2 ': '0 1  12  12  39  37  39  39  48 ',
  ' 3 ': '0 1  19  19  41  39  41  41  50 ',
  ' 4 ': '0 1  10  10  32  30  32  32  41 ',

Comment: maybe you add a link to a fiddle with the data and the code. the i have a look to it.

Comment: Hey, I have fixed this issue. Thank you for me helping out.